# Instalação do Maverick faz o servidor parar de funcionar

Tags: php, mysql, apache, osx

Sou novato com apples e recentemente comprei um mac book, com o sistema operacional Lion. Instalei o php, mysql, etc e tudo funcionou perfeitamente.

Agora atualizei o sistema para o Maverick e o servidor parou de funcionar.
Quando digito no browser localhost/~username/project, ao invés de mostrar o site PHP, aparece a árvore de pastas.

O que fazer?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas preferências do sistema, em compartilhamento. Se o compartilhamento web estiver ativado, você está usando o apache da instalação do OSX. E é possível que a atualização tenha sobrescrito o que você instalou, dependendo de onde você instalou.

Comment: Você está usando instalações padrões do `php` `mysql`? ou instalou algum pacote como o `XAMPP`?

Answer (score 3):

Para reabilitar o PHP faça o seguinte procedimento

Abra o terminal

Digite o seguinte comando

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Digite sua senha de usuário

Irá abrir a configuração do apache. Procure a linha

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Aperte i para começar a editar e retire o # no inicio da linha. Aperte ESC e depois :wq E aperte ENTER

Logo em seguida

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Teste e veja se o php voltou a funcionar

Recomendo abrir um arquivo com phpinfo() para ver conferir se as conigurações continuam iguais.

Caso possua alguma outra dúvida sobre o assunto:

http://akrabat.com/computing/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-mavericks/